# How to center content relative to cell?

Tags: css

I have a fiddle up here:

http://jsfiddle.net/robvious/e5QVZ/

I'm trying to keep the section text centered in the available whitespace, but it seems to be sticking to the right.  How can I center it relative to the "cell"?

```html
<aside id="side-browser">
    <a href="#">Folder One</a> <br/>
    <a href="#">Folder Two</a><br/>
    <a href="#">Folder Three</a><br/>
</aside>
<section>
    <h1>Section Content</h1>
</section>
```

```css
section {
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;  
}

aside {  
    display: table-cell;  
    width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Section seems to be centered in your fiddle already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as PSCoder mentiond, your text is already centered. I have updated your fiddle to illustrate what is happening. http://jsfiddle.net/e5QVZ/28/

As 3bu1 alluded to, you need to adjust your widths until your desired affect is achieved.

To  make it obvious I have added a container div with a fixed width of 500px,

```
#container{width:500px;border:1px dotted #09c;}
section {background-color:#afa;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:200px;
}

aside {background-color:#faa;  
    display: table-cell;  
    width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Wow!  Totally missed this.  Thanks luke.

Answer (score 0):

```
section {
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell; 
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
```